Jenkins API - asynchPeople returns only 1 user
I am having a strange issue where when using Jenkins API to fetch users using the call - asynchPeople/api/json?depth=2 I am only getting in the response 1 user back, even though we have a lot more.
Any idea why it may happen?
Thanks!
